# Align some part of string in Option tag

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I would like to make groups of the text content of an `<option />` tag. Say I have the following:

```
<select>
  <option>CCB - AFHT Crew Balancing</option>
  <option>WFM - Force Majere</option>
  ....
  ....
  <option>WWW - Adjacent TRK Form B</option>
  <option>MAH - Air Hose Separation</option>
  ....
  ....
  <option>IIS - Chassis Shortage RR</option>
  <option>WFL - Flooding</option>               
</select>
```

In UI, the dropdown displaying like this ↓ ,      but I have to display like this ↓

[image]  [image]

I was thinking of doing something like

`<option><span style="width:30px;">CCB</span><span>- AFHT Crew Balancing</span></option>`

But It is not working because Options tag won't allow any other sub tags.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with `span`s in `option` tags, but perhaps using a monospace font and formatting the display text to fixed column widths would be a solution

Comment: And actually, looking at your example, if all of your first columns are always the same length with the same separator (i.e. 3 letter codes followed by a space a dash and a space) then you could just use any monospace font and it should work.  (This also looks like what the right half of the image is doing vs the left)

Comment: I agree with @arcyqwerty, either use a monospace font, or maybe try using the tab  character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a monospace font so every character has the same width:

```
<select style="font-family:'Courier New'">
  <option>CCB - AFHT Crew Balancing</option>
  <option>WFM - Force Majere</option>
  <option>WWW - Adjacent TRK Form B</option>
  <option>MAH - Air Hose Separation</option>
  <option>IIS - Chassis Shortage RR</option>
  <option>WFL - Flooding</option>               
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha6f4opy/)